# Problem with login page. Next.Js 13 chat-app project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth, next.js13

I have a issue with login page in my project. I'm using NextAuth, Prisma, TypeScript and Next.Js. I have this error:

```
No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'email'. Either declare one or provide an initializer.ts(18004)
```

I've created this login page on app/login directory

```
'use client'
import router, {useRouter} from "next/router";
import Link from 'next/link'
import React, { MouseEventHandler, useState } from 'react'
import styles from '../styles/loginpage.module.scss'
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";




interface LoginProps {
  onClick: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>
  onChange: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>
}



export default function LoginComponent({}: LoginProps) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("")
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
  const [loginError, setLoginError] = useState('');
  const handleLogin = (e: React.SyntheticEvent)  => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

   const data =  signIn("credentials", {email, password, callbackUrl: `${window.location.origin}/dashboard`, redirect: false }
    ).then(function(result: any){
        if (result.error !== null)
        {
            if (result.status === 401)
            {
                setLoginError("Your username/password combination was incorrect. Please try again");
            }
            else
            {
                setLoginError(result.error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            router.push(result.url);
        }
    });
}
  
  
  
  
  return (
    <div className= {styles.registerBody}>
      <div className={styles.loginDiv} >
        <h1 className={styles.banner}>Login</h1>
        <h4 className={styles.description}>Please enter your Login and your Password </h4>
        <form  onSubmit={handleLogin}>
        {loginError}
        <input className={styles.formInput} value={email} onChange={(event) => setUser(event.target.value)} type="text" placeholder='Email'/>
        <input value={password} className={styles.formInput} onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)} type="password" placeholder='Password'/>
        <button type='submit' className={styles.button} >Login</button>
        </form>
        
        <p className={styles.question}>Not sign yet? <Link href={"../register"}>Register</Link> now</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
  
}
```

And this is [...nextAuth.js] file that I've created at pages/api/directory. I've declared "email" property on this file.

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next/types';
import { AuthOptions } from 'next-auth/core/types';
let userAccount:any = null;

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const confirmPasswordHash = (plainPassword: any, hashedPassword: string) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        bcrypt.compare(plainPassword, hashedPassword, function(err: any, res: unknown) {
            resolve(res);
        });
    })
}

const configuration = {
    cookie: {
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    },
    session: {
        jwt: true,
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60
    },
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            id: "credentials",
            name: "credentials",
            credentials: {},
            async authorize(credentials : any) {
                try
                {
                    const user = await prisma.users.findFirst({
                        where: {
                            email: credentials.email
                        }
                    });

                    if (user !== null)
                    {
                        //Compare the hash
                        const res = await confirmPasswordHash(credentials.password, user.password);
                        if (res === true)
                        {
                            userAccount = {
                                userId: user.userId,
                                firstName: user.firstName,
                                lastName: user.lastName,
                                email: user.email,
                                isActive: user.isActive
                            };
                            return userAccount;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            console.log("Hash not matched logging in");
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                catch (err)
                {
                    console.log("Authorize error:", err);
                }

            }
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async signIn(user: { user: any; userId: any; isActive: string; }, account: any, profile: any) {
            try
            {
                //the user object is wrapped in another user object so extract it
                user = user.user;
                console.log("Sign in callback", user);
                console.log("User id: ", user.userId)
                if (typeof user.userId !== typeof undefined)
                {

                    if (user.isActive === '1')
                    {
                        console.log("User is active");
                        return user;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log("User is not active")
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("User id was undefined")
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (err)
            {
                console.error("Signin callback error:", err);
            }

        },
        async register(firstName: string, lastName: string, email: string, password: string) {
            try
            {
                await prisma.users.create({
                    data: {
                        firstName: firstName,
                        lastName: lastName,
                        email: email,
                        password: password
                    }
                })
                return true;
            }
            catch (err)
            {
                console.error("Failed to register user. Error", err);
                return false;
            }

        },
        async session(session: { user: { userId: any; name?: string; email?: any; }; token: any; }, token: { user: any; }) {
            if (userAccount !== null)
            {
                //session.user = userAccount;
                session.user = {
                    userId: userAccount.userId,
                    name: `${userAccount.firstName} ${userAccount.lastName}`,
                    email: userAccount.email
                }

            }
            else if (typeof token.user !== typeof undefined && (typeof session.user === typeof undefined
                || (typeof session.user !== typeof undefined && typeof session.user.userId === typeof undefined)))
            {
                session.user = token.user;
            }
            else if (typeof token !== typeof undefined)
            {
                session.token = token;
            }
            return session;
        },
        async jwt(token: { user: any; }, user: any, account: any, profile: any, isNewUser: any) {
            console.log("JWT callback. Got User: ", user);
            if (typeof user !== typeof undefined)
            {
                token.user = user;
            }
            return token;
        }
    }
}
export default (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse, configuration: AuthOptions) => NextAuth(req, res, configuration)
```

I've checked my prisma schema and mysql database and I've created email property. What should I've check to get rid of this error. Maybe I've declared something wrong?